# Where to capture onResume in Android MVC ViewController structure

Tags: android, jtwitter

I have taken over maintenance of an Android application that uses MVC with a `ViewController` interface.

Part of the revisions I'm making are to add `JTwitter` links.  I am being challenged on the `JTwitter Authorization` where I'm expecting to get a callback.

Where would I capture the `onResume` or `onNewIntent` events when a callback occurs?

My class is defines as:

`public class ExportTwitterScreen extends BasicViewController<ExportTwitterScreenView>`

I have tried putting the `onResume` in the `BasicViewController` but that does nothing for me.

Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be more of an Android question than a JTwitter one.

For authorisation in Android, see the [AndroidTwitterLogin](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/index.html?winterwell/jtwitter/android/AndroidTwitterLogin.html) class. The javadoc gives an example of how to use it. It should be easy.

Comment: I am attempting to get the Authorization Token and Secret, not logging in!

Comment: Perhaps if you rephrase your question, and maybe add a code snippet?